# Altair- How to Display All Axis

Tags: python, altair

I have the code below and how can I reorder the days of the week to the proper order, and make sure the weeks of the year with missing data get displayed

This is the code I have

```
import pandas as pd
import altair as alt
df = pd.read_parquet(
    "https://github.com/anly503/datasets/raw/main/hk_hospital_wait.parquet"
)

(alt.Chart(df)
 .mark_rect()
 .encode(
    alt.X("week", title="Week"),
    alt.Y("wkday_name", title="Weekday")
        ,color=alt.Color('mean(max_wait):Q', scale=alt.Scale(scheme='orangered'))
        )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

To sort the weekdays, you can set the scale's domain to a sorted list of the weekdays. To show the empty weeks, you can encode week as an ordinal variable (if you also want to show all weeks between 9 and 46, you could set the scale's domain on the x-axis as well to include all numbers 1-52):

```py
import pandas as pd
import altair as alt
import calendar


alt.data_transformers.enable('data_server')

df = pd.read_parquet(
    "https://github.com/anly503/datasets/raw/main/hk_hospital_wait.parquet"
)

# You could also write out the weekdays by hand
sorted_weekdays = list(calendar.day_abbr)

alt.Chart(df).mark_rect().encode(
    alt.X("week:O"),
    alt.Y("wkday_name", scale=alt.Scale(domain=sorted_weekdays)),
    alt.Color('mean(max_wait):Q')
)
```

[image]

Comment: Do you know how to set the scale's domain on the x-axis to include all numbers from 1 to 53

Comment: @Zhang Yes, it's the same way as above using `domain` and passing  a list with all unique numbers e.g. `list(range(53))`